# How to build a Windows Development Environment in AWS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, github, aws-codecommit

What is the procedure to build a secure windows development environment in AWS for C# code in Visual Studio?

Due to code protection and restricting code leakage, I have to set up a remote dev environment in AWS where the team connects using Thin Clients to the instances for daily development.

Is code Commit good for locking down Repo clone / read/write to an AWS Instance VM? if not can someone recommend a better solution? Github would be ideal, we use deploy keeps on Ubuntu VM's for the same thing, this way they don't have access to the Github UI to download the code from the website and they cannot clone or export onto another pc.

Following this what is the best way to secure the VM to keep the code only on the VM but then allow them to commit on the VM so it can be pushed to code deploy?

Also is better to set up a Server 2016 instance or use AWS workspaces for a VM as they will be primarily running Visual Studio 2016

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are mixing up several unrelated things. Essentially, you are asking if there's an AMR with Visual Studio installed. I'm sure there is. What does `Is Code Commit go` even mean though? Based on *what* criteria? Why would *Github* be more secure? And why put everyone on the same *VM*? Shouldn't each developer have his/her *own* VM?

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, Typo. Each Dev will have their own VM. at the moment in Ubuntu they remote dev on the server, commit via GitHub deploy keys and all that works fine. I am looking for something equivalent for windows development using VS017. The main critera are to allow remote access to the VM's so they can work at home and we can scale the VM's as some of the applications are quite resource heavy. Next its to stop the code from being emailed, copied, transferred whatever. I can modify the policies to prevent / limit this.

I am looking for a practical solution to complete these objectives

Comment: You don't need a VM for this. You need training in version control. Anyway, *Azure* already has VS development VMs, *and* a very strong version control, project management, build server, etc. suite in VSTS. It's equivalent or better in many places than Github.

Comment: I'd also say that something like "you don't deploy unless it's through the build server or else" with a pretty strong "or else" would help. It's hard to imagine professional developers emailing code to each other when Git is available. As long as you provide the training of course

Comment: We are fully adapt to git, our whole team uses it. we had a case of a developer sharing our code from our business repo he was working on and due to this the main premise is to block / stop / limit / derisk code sharing hence why i am looking for remote development, we can't afford git enterprise and only in that ( in the github suite) can you limit clone by an IP.

all code they write needs to be commuted to either code start, gitlab, or github whatever is best for code protection / security and then we code review before build. Does VSTS work for this?

Comment: *that* is a different requirement than the entire question. You'll have to check the types of restrictions offered by Code Commit or VSTS, although I expect VSTS to be stronger there. Just looking at [conditional access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/manage-conditional-access) it supports restrictions by IP, 2FA, and other restrictions offered by Azure Active Directory.